# Trouble adding buttons to tables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add several buttons to a table using javascript, however I keep being offered this result with `[objectHTMLInputElement]`

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function createDiseaseTable(country){
    var displayCountry = document.getElementById("countrySelected");
    displayCountry.innerHTML = country.name;
    var diseaseTable = document.getElementById("diseases");
    diseaseTable.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i<country.diseases.length; i++) ////////////////////////////////////
    {
        var changeDisease = document.createElement('input');
        changeDisease.type = 'button';
        changeDisease.name = "x"
        changeDisease.onclick = hi();
        var row = diseaseTable.insertRow(i);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3)
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell1.innerHTML = OurDiseases[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = OurDiseases[i].cureLevel;
        cell3.innerHTML = OurDiseases[i].killLevel;
        cell4.innerHTML = OurDiseases[i].cured;
        cell5.innerHTML = changeDisease;
        console.log(changeDisease);
    }
    var row = diseaseTable.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Disease";
    cell2.innerHTML = "Level needed to cure";
    cell3.innerHTML = "Deaths each year";   
    cell4.innerHTML = "Cured";
    cell5.innerHTML = "More Info";

}
```

Note: I'm not concerned about not running a function yet upon click, i just want the actual button to appear

Comment: You have to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) the newly created element to a parent. I.e. instead of `cell5.innerHTML = changeDisease;` you need `cell5.appendChild(changeDisease);` Just as a side note, it's easy to insert rows at the end of a table by passing simply `-1` as argument to `insertRow()`, the same stands for cells and `insertCell()`.

Comment: Old versions of Internet Explorer won't let you set the "type" of an `<input>` element after it's been created. You have to use `document.createElement("<input type=button>>")` instead.

Comment: @Pointy Never seen that happening. Anyway, `.createElement("<input type=button>")` would break the code in newer browsers ...

Comment: @Teemu it changed with IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `appendChild` function

your code could than look like this:

```
...
cell5.appendChild(changeDisease);
...
```

You can find more details on this function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

**Update - see comment:**

`name` is an attribute of an element and not the caption of the button, if you want to set the caption use the attribute `value` instead - here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button

Comment: Thanks, that has given me something to click! But the button hasn't got its name 'x' written on it. How do I access that?

Comment: that's a different question, but the name is a totally different property and not at all what you are looking for when you want to set the caption, use `value` instead (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done DOM manipulation without jQuery, but I believe you need to do `cell5.appendChild(changeDiseas)` rather than .innerHTML (which is expecting an HTML string).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp